# Linux Mint KDE - USB mouse left clicks do not work

Tags: linux, mouse, linux-mint, kde, metacity

The issue is not with the mouse, as it works on other computers (and on this one, for about five minutes after a reboot). Right clicks and mouse movement are fine. Left clicks with the touchpad work fine.

[this](https://superuser.com/questions/72112/mouse-clicks-suddenly-stopped-working-in-ubuntu) question seems relevant, but the answer is for people running `compiz`. I don't think I'm running compiz, as `which compiz` gives me `compiz not found`.

EDIT: as of right now `metacity --replace&` does nothing except make my windows look ugly and screw up my taskbar.

Comment: As you're a low reputation user: If an answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of the text, which means "yes, this is THE answer"!

Comment: @Hannu I'll be sure to do that when THE answer arrives. Thanks.

Comment: What hardware platform? I have similar behavior w/USB mouse under LM 18 Cinnamon, but it also happens with the Lenovo's built-in TrackPoint "mouse" keys and the touchpad's keys. I.e., it does not seem to be hardware exactly. Keys work or not consistently; i.e., *always* work when clicking task-bar Menu selections but *never* when clicking desktop icons, etc. Haven't found a pattern yet.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a hardware problem in the computer.

Electronics can die in such a manner that a specific function stops working as the circuitry involved gets "warm" (as from having been running [powered on] for a anything between a few minutes to hours).