# Left mouse button stopped working

Tags: usb, mouse, ubuntu-20.04

Today my left mouse button stopped working. Touchpad still works but USB cable mouse does not.

I tired :

- system restart
- gnome reset
- unplug mouse
- metacity --replace &
- read [Mouse clicks suddenly stopped working in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/72112/mouse-clicks-suddenly-stopped-working-in-ubuntu)

syslog show this error, if I plug in the mouse:

> systemd-udevd[297662]: 1-3: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper
> bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3 189:13'
> failed with exit code 1. systemd-udevd[297662]: 1-3: Process
>
> '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter
> /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3 189:13' failed with exit
> code 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the mouse is broken and you'll have to replace it. Test it with a different computer to make sure.

Fixing just the button may be possible, but you'd need parts, tools and soldering skills.

The error is related to CUPS which manages printers, not mice.

Comment: Thanks! Turned out to be a defective contact. Did not work on other PC. Started working again on the main PC.